# jQuery UI 1.6 and adding slider in Drupal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drupal-6

I can't use new version of jQuery. I have 1.6.

I have in head ui.core, ui.slider, but when I call $('#min-price').slider();  I am getting:

> $("#min-price").slider is not a function

I call it when DOM is ready.

Could somebody help?

**code added**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var wrapper = $('<span id="snuper-sorter-wrapper">Sort by: </span>'),
        dealsDivCopy = $('.view .views-row').clone(true),
        dealsCategories = $('#deals-categories'),
        currentDeals = Drupal.settings.snuper_filter.deals;


        $('#min-price').slider(); //here it fails
//rest of code
```

How can I examine that jquery ui object exists and get function list?

**EDIT**

My fault, I need to load it in different way.

In Drupal you add jQuery element this way:

```
jquery_ui_add(array('ui.slider'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have loaded both libraries (jQuery and the jQueryUI) and also make sure the paths to the files are correct.

Comment: Maybe try to download the (newest) library file again (not compressed). Or maybe it is clashing with another javascript library or such you are using. Check that also.

Comment: I use Drupal 6, I try load jQuery UI 1.8 but it collide with older version. I can't remove 1.6 because Drupal 6 modules needs 1.6 version and site go down when I do it